# Self assessment Tax not reflecting 26AS

Tags: income-tax, india

I paid Self Assessment on 24/6/2019 before noon. Chart status enquiry on 28th confirms receipt of amount in TIN on 27th. But till 30th 11:30 AM it is not reflected in 26AS. How long will it take to be reflected in form 26AS?

Comment: Any reason why you are looking for 26AS

Comment: the income tax department India swears by form 26AS. if payment is not reflected in 26AS they will send notice for that amount leading to double payment.

Answer (score 0):

Advance taxes paid takes a while to reflect. ITR can be submitted by giving the details. There is absolutely no issues. I have been doing this for a decade and there is no enquiry